# How to select/deselect all items in listview on button click in flutter?

Tags: flutter, listview, listviewitem, multipleselection, flutter-listview

I want to deselect all items of ListView on clicking the none button.

Here is my code:

```
GridView gridItems() {
    return GridView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          mainAxisSpacing: 16,
          crossAxisSpacing: 10,
          childAspectRatio: 2.5),
      //scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: List.generate(blocks.length, (index) {
        return MaterialButton(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
              side: BorderSide(color: borderGreyColor, width: 1)),

          //selected: paints[index].selected,
          child: Text(
            blocks[index].title.toString(),
            style: TextStyle(
                color: blocks[index].isSelected ? whiteColor : greyColor,
                fontFamily: 'PoppinsRegular',
                fontSize: 12),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              blocks[index].isSelected = !blocks[index].isSelected;
              if (blocks[0].isSelected == true) {
                setState(() {
                  for (var i = 1; i < blocks.length; i++) {
                    blocks[i].isSelected = false;
                  }
                });
              }
              //log(blocks[index].isSelected.toString());
            });
          },
          color: blocks[index].isSelected ? primaryColor : whiteColor,
        );
      }),
    );
```

Comment: Ur code is not aligned properly, please do it.

Comment: So where is your button, what did you try, what happened when you ran it and what did you expect to happen instead?